# Adnace Update - update col in one table by fetching data from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having two tables

```
Questionnaires
id
project_id

Project_cycles
id
project_id
questionnaire_id
```

with records like these at the moment

```
Questionnaires
id        project_id
1          1
2          2
3          3
4          3

Project_cycles
id     project_id       questionanire_id
1         1                 null
2         2                 null
----
```

What I want to do is to copy the correct questionnaire_id on the `Project_cycles` table. Is it possible to do this with one query or nested queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, perform a `UPDATE JOIN` like

```
UPDATE Project_cycles a 
    JOIN Questionnaires b ON a.project_id  = b.project_id 
SET a.questionanire_id = b.id;
```

Comment: The `a` and `b` stand for aliases of the tables in this case?

Comment: @Lykos, absolutely ... they are not mandate but better for redability

Comment: One last question, I promise, just to confirm. This will work even if I have the same `project_id` more that once in `Project_cycles`, right?

Comment: @Lykos, yes it will absolutely